# I want to post this json string to server using loop j

Tags: android, json

Here is what I want to post on server

```
{

"name":"testOne",
"location": "['one','two','three']"

}
```

Here is the code I always get this error `{"message":"IntegrityError"}`

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    String someData="{\"name\":\"testOne\",\"location\": \"[\'ne\',\'two\',\'three\']\"}";


    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(someData);
    Log.e("Json", String.valueOf(entity));
    client.post(MainActivity.this, "http://impero-dannyfast.rhcloud.com/api/agents", entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SUcc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fail"+errorResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.e("Tag:", String.valueOf(errorResponse));

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception caught in your Django server.

**Definition of the error:**

> Exception raised when the relational integrity of the database is
>   affected, e.g. a foreign key check fails, duplicate key, etc.

Source: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/IntegrityError

Comment: Thanks for your time